# How to set an event listener inside a loop using closures

Tags: javascript, closures, dom-events

```
thisKey.addEventListener(
  'mousedown',
  (function(_temp) {
    return function() {
      fnPlayKeyboard({
        keyCode: _temp
      });
    }
  })(reverseLookup[n + ',' + i])
);
```

Saw this line of code and I'm confused as to how the function in the second parameter of addEventListener works. I know that the overall goal is to play the correct sound when a key on a keyboard is clicked.

In the rest of the code, fnPlayKeyboard takes in an event e as parameter and plays the note based on e.keyCode. reverseLookup should look up a keyCode given a music note which here is represented by n+','+i.

I'm guessing the code is somehow translating a mousedown event to a keydown event but not sure how it's doing this. Particularly confusing to me is the syntax because there seems to be a double ()() as the 2nd parameter of addEventListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a function that gets called immediately and returns another function. That returned function then gets assigned as the mousedown listener.

It *might* be so convoluted due to being an attempt to create a function-scoped variable `_temp` in order to get out of the closure-inside-loops issue. If ES2015 is permitted, it would be much clearer. The code is equivalent to:

```
// ES2015
const keyCode = reverseLookup[n + ',' + i];
thisKey.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  fnPlayKeyboard({ keyCode });
});
```

It takes the `n` and `i` variables, whatever they are, and looks them up on `reverseLookup`, which is presumably an object, to get a `keyCode`. Then, when `thisKey` receives a `mousedown` event, it calls `fnPlayKeyboard` with an object with that `keyCode`.

The code is *not* necessarily equivalent to

```
// Pre-ES2015
var keyCode = reverseLookup[n + ',' + i];
thisKey.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  fnPlayKeyboard({ keyCode: keyCode });
});
```

because, if the code is inside a loop, there will only be one binding for `keyCode` (which will be the final value assigned to it in the final iteration of the loop):

```
// Pre-ES2015
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var keyCode = reverseLookup[n + ',' + i];
  thisKey.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    fnPlayKeyboard({ keyCode: keyCode });
  });
}
```

The above code would not work as expected, but fixing it by declaring the variable with `const` instead is only permitted in ES2015+ environments. In older environments, calling the anonymous `(function(_temp) { return function() {` immediately in the `addEventListener` is one way to make sure the listener will have the correct `keyCode` when called, by creating a function-scoped variable (the `_temp` parameter) just for this listener.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you explain what the double (...)(...) means: ```(function(_temp)...)(reverseLookup[...])``` How is reverseLookup being passed into function(_temp)?

Comment: It's a function that returns a function. The `(reverseLookup[n + ',' + i])` is the argument list. When the interpreter comes across the `addEventListener` line, it evaluates the arguments to pass to the inner function (the `function(_temp) { return function() { fnPlayKeyboard({keyCode:_temp}); } }`). It comes up with a something for `(reverseLookup[n + ',' + i])`, then passes it to the function, with that "something" as the `_temp` parameter.